# lftp catch output for progress bar

Tags: bash, wget, zenity, lftp, yad

how I can use unbuffer to capture each output line for lftp? I would like to use this information to update a zenity/yad progress bar. Only after upload I get the full file... With wget works like a charm.

Thanks,
Michael

Here my code:

```
unbuffer -p lftp -e 'put /home/bld/xx12.deb; bye' -u ftp,11111 san.rrr.com | sed -u 's/\([0-9]\)%//' > file2
```

the output:

```
open `san.rrr.com' [Löse Hostadresse auf...]

»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 0 (ffff) [FEAT Verbindungsaufbau...]
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 0 (0%) [Warte auf Antwort...]       
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 655376 (8%) [Sende Daten]      
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 1160536 (14%) 533.0K/s ca. fertig:13s [Sende Daten]
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 1700736 (20%) 547.1K/s ca. fertig:11s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 2173776 (26%) 589.9K/s ca. fertig:10s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 2626376 (32%) 580.3K/s ca. fertig:9s [Sende Daten]   
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 3236656 (39%) 604.9K/s ca. fertig:8s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 3797296 (46%) 617.8K/s ca. fertig:7s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 4425096 (54%) 632.8K/s ca. fertig:6s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 5045596 (62%) 652.0K/s ca. fertig:5s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 5667556 (69%) 660.5K/s ca. fertig:4s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 6283676 (77%) 665.7K/s ca. fertig:3s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 6746496 (83%) 658.2K/s ca. fertig:2s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 7244356 (89%) 658.9K/s ca. fertig:1s [Sende Daten]  
»/home/bld/xx12.deb« bei 8099411 (100%) 684.1K/s ca. fertig:0s [Warte auf Übertragun

8099411 Bytes übertragen in 13 Sekunden (627.2K/s)
```

Wget code:

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.4/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.4-102546~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb 2>&1 | sed -u 's/.*//' > file1
```

Comment: Is `lftp` a requirement? `curl` has a nice option, `-#`

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: curl is a little bit slow... so I find "wput" and that’s my choice!